Nested if statement in C not executing inner if
Struggling (newbie) with a nested if in C, probably doing something stupid.
Basically a switch down tester which determines whether just down for a second or longer.
void SwitchTest(void) 
{
    __delay_ms(3000);
    // LEDCOM = LED_ON;            // Connect Bar Common
    LED1 = LED_OFF; 
    LED2 = LED_OFF; 
    LED3 = LED_OFF; 
    LED4 = LED_OFF; 
    LED5 = LED_OFF; 
        
    if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 1)       // Is the Status Button pressed (high = no)
    { 
        GoSleep();                  // No, Sleep    
    }
    else if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 0)  
    {
        __delay_ms(1000);             // Yes, retest in 1 sec
        if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 1)       // Is the Status Button still pressed (low = yes)
        {
            LED1 = LED_ON;               // No, turn on LED1    
            __delay_ms(3000); 
            DisplayStep();                // No, display previous step    
        }
        else
        {    
            return;                       // Yes, resume main loop 
        }
    }  
}

The GoSleep() and return; parts work but the code for LED1 ON and DisplayStep() never occurs (yet it does seem to recognise that the switch was down for less than 1 second.
This code (asm) works
btfsc  PORTA,0         ; Is the switch pressed (0)
     goto   GoRest          ; No, sleep
     call   Wait0.5s        ; Yes, retest in 1sec
    ; call  Wait0.5s
     btfsc  PORTA,0         ; Is the switch still pressed (0)
     goto   DisplayStep     ; No, Display previous led_step
     return                 ; Yes, resume MainLoop


The nested if can never be true. It's inside if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 0), so how can PORTAbits.RA1 == 1 be true?

Unless PORTAbits can change while you call __delay_ms(1000).

OT: If you have if (a == 1) { ... } else if (a == 0) { ... }, and assuming that a can only be 0 or 1, then it's the same as if (a == 1) { ... } else { ... }. Also, there's no need for your explicit return statement in that function.

probably __delay_ms(1000);  is not enough for the reset, have you tried with a longer pause?

You might need to declare PORTAbits as volatile to keep the optimizer from assuming that it doesn't change while __delay_ms() is running.

The delay is to determine whether the switch was down for les than 1 second. Originaly I didn't have the if else, because only one test is necessary, then the same test after a delay. It's nothing to do with timing.

@Ralph Unless a variable is declared volatile, the compiler is free to assume that it won't change unless the code changes it. If PORTAbits.RA1 is non-volatile, any decent compiler will assume that the inner test is always false, therefore redundant, and compile the whole second branch to return. volatile is how you tell the compiler that PORTAbits.RA1 is a memory-mapped variable that can change and needs to be retested instead of using the previous value.

... though the details of exactly where the volatile keyword needs to go depend on how PORTAbits is defined.

Thanks, it was just syntax, I simplified it and had to put an empty else statement in the nested if else, otherwise it breaks.

What is the expected behaviour? Because the code logic is not obvious. What is your question?

Embedded systems beginner classes typically addresses the concept of "debouncing", which is a way to compensate for electromechanical bounces of switches etc by means or repeated reads and filtering. It's naive to think you can go without it and get stable input readings. The easiest way to do that is to have a cyclic timer reading the switches once every 10ms and then bitwise AND the results with the previous read. As a bonus this also acts as a bit of EMI filtering.

Similarly, the current code doesn't test if a button has been pressed continuously, it only tests if it was pressed at two separate times. The rule of thumb for bare metal embedded systems is to never use busy-wait delays at any place in the program.

      if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 1)       // Is the Status Button pressed (high = no)
      { 
        GoSleep();                  // No, Sleep    
      }
      else if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 0)  

Your logic is wrong.  if PORTAbits.RA1 != 1 then it has to be 0. So checking it in the else makes no sense. Basically you always enter the second if (nested one) when in else part of the first if
IT is not what you want.
if (PORTAbits.RA1 == 1)       // Is the Status Button still pressed (low = yes) it is high not low.  You check the wrong condition. (you should compare to 0 not 1

It's a possibly unnecessary condition, but it isn't wrong. The nested if the question is referring to is not this one.

Thanks, The delay is to determine whether the switch was down for les than 1 second. Originally I didn't have the if else, because only one test is necessary, then the same test after a delay. It's nothing to do with timing. I have the code working in asm but I just can't get it to work in C.

The last paragraph you added is wrong as well. 1 indicates that the button is not pressed according to the comments, which is what the code wants to test.

The operation should be, is the button up then do A,, is the button down, if down for less than 1 sec then do B, if down for more than 1 second do C
